# How to find the exact value of the cosine of 50 degree angle

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know the exact value of $\cos 50^\circ$.

Actually I have already tried lot of times to solve but I cannot find the exact value of $\cos 50^\circ$.

Comment: Firstly you will have to find $3$ degree here which can be done from $cos (75-72)$ but main problem is now you have to find $1$ too by setting up a cubic equation and finding it's root. After finding value of 1 write $cos 50$ as $cos 48+2$

Comment: It is an irrational number, so what do you mean "exact value"?

Comment: Maybe he means in term of radicals^

Comment: Exact value for ex sin30=1/2 this is the exact value not sin30=0.5 I don't want that

Comment: 0.5 is the same thing as 1/2

Comment: Yes I mean radical

Comment: I want the exact value in radical :)

Comment: What difference does it make? That's the exact same thing:

$$0.5=\frac{5}{10}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Peak it's possible but it's really really very long.

Comment: Yes Mann you are right :)

Comment: Oh can u give me some hint?

Comment: Look my first comment.

Comment: Actually it seem very confused

Comment: So how about can u solve cos35cos85 for me?

Comment: Yes, but as i said it will take too long, there are defined values of 72 and 75 look them over net. Use $\cos 3\theta = 4 \cos^{3}\theta-3 \cos \theta$ to find $\cos 1 $ this will be a cubic equation. Then you can find each and every value which is not fractional, congratulation.

Comment: naybe see http://www.topcoaching.com/ask/question/1617/12/All/answered/cos-35---cos85---cos-155----

Comment: @PeakMang For $\cos(35)\cos(85)$ use $\cos(105)=\cos(210/2)$ with half-angle, and then the triple angle formula since $\cos(35)=\cos(105/3).$  For $\cos(85),$ use half angle formula twice to get $\cos(7.5)$ from $\cos(30),$ and then notice that $35+7.5=42.5,$ which is half $85.$  It can be done, if you are dedicated!

Answer (score 4):

one method can be:
$$\cos 3x =4\cos^3x-3\cos x$$
Putting $x=50$ gives $$\cos 150 =4\cos^3x-3\cos x\tag{*}$$
But $\cos 150=-\cos 30=-{\sqrt 3\over 2}$.
So you have the LHS of  $({}^*)$. Therefore We have to solve the following equation using [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method):
$$4t^3-3t+{\sqrt 3\over 2}=0$$

where $t=\cos 50$.

Comment: Wow incredible thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I don't see how $\left(\frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{1/3}$ can be considered more exact value rather than $\cos \frac{5\pi}{18}$

Comment: You know every polynomial equation of an odd degree has a real root.

Comment: But brother I can't factor it

Comment: How to factor it ????

Comment: Please take a look at the give link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: Yes I know it but this is not simple one

Comment: @PeakMang , use wolfram alpha to solve that equation.

Comment: Could also use the vieta formulas which relate the coefficients of a polynomial to symmetric polynomials in its roots http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html, they even give an example for a general cubic

Comment: A standard trick for equations of the form $x^3+ax+b=0$ is to make the substitution $x=z-\dfrac{a} {3z}.$

Answer (score 0):

TO use Cardano's method for the cubic, first divide by $4,$ to write $4t^3-3t+\sqrt{3}/2=0$ as $$t^3-\frac{3t}4+\frac{\sqrt{3}}8=0.$$

Now let $t=x+\frac1{4x},$ so that the equation becomes
$$\left(x+\frac1{4x}\right)^3-\frac34\left(x+\frac1{4x}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}8=0.$$
Then multiplying by $64x^3$ and expanding, we have
$$64x^6+(8\sqrt3)x^3+1=0,$$
where a bunch of terms cancel. Now that we have a quadratic form, using the quadratic formula gives:
$$x^3=\frac{-\sqrt3\pm i}{16}.$$
Now this equation has 6 solutions, and all 6 are complex, but when you use
$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-\sqrt3+i}{16}},$$ and take $t=x+\dfrac1{4x},$ you get $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{-\sqrt3+i}{16}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4(-\sqrt3+i)}},$$ which is a real number approximately equal to $0.6427876\approx\cos(50^\circ).$

**Now it would be a real treat if someone could 'Mathematica' the result to write it without depending on $i.$**

Comment: There's not going to be a way to write this result that doesn't depend on $i$.  See [this blog post](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/the-cubic-formula-is-a-scam-and-galois-can-prove-it/) by David Speyer.

Comment: @JimBelk, sorry - 'tongue-in-cheek' comment!

Answer (score 0):

here is my own calculation, you can use cofunction identities
$$\cos 50°=\sin\left(90°-50°\right)=\sin 40°=\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}$$
set $\zeta^{k}$ as ninth roots of unity, we can found using De Moivre Formula that
$$\zeta^{k}+\zeta^{9-k}=2\cos\frac{2k\pi}{9}$$
$$\zeta^{k}-\zeta^{9-k}=2i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{9}$$
$$\zeta^{k}-2+\zeta^{9-k}=-4\sin^2\frac{2k\pi}{9}$$
$$-4\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}=2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}-2$$
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}-2}}{2}$$
then, we will need to solve $2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}$ , which is the roots of the polynomial
$$\left(x-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)\left(x-2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)\left(x-2\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}\right)=0$$
$$x^3-3x+1=0$$
now we left with the cubic polynomial with the interesting form
$$x^3-3px+2q=0$$
where $p=1$ , and $q=\frac{1}{2}$ .

Cubic Formula gives
$$x=\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}}\right)$$
consequently
$$x=\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)$$
$$2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)$$
$$2\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)$$
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}-2}}{2}$$
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\left(-6+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)}}{2}$$
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{\frac{3}{9}\left(-6+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)}}{2}$$
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{3\left(-6+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)}}{6}$$
$$\cos 50°=\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}=-\frac{i\sqrt{-18+\frac{-3-3i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-3+3i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}}}{6}$$
however, solving directly using $\cos 3\theta = 4\cos^3 \theta -3\cos \theta$ unexpectedly gives
$$\cos 20°=\sqrt[3]{\frac{i-\sqrt3}{16}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4(i-\sqrt3)}}$$
consequently
$$\cos 20°=\sqrt[3]{\frac{i-\sqrt3}{16}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{i+\sqrt3}{16}}$$
$$\cos 20°=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4i-4\sqrt3}{64}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{4i+4\sqrt3}{64}}$$
$$\cos 20°=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt[3]{4i-4\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt[3]{4i+4\sqrt3}$$
the other roots is what do we wanted
$$\cos 50°=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i-4\sqrt3}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i+4\sqrt3}$$
$$\cos 80°=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i-4\sqrt3}+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i+4\sqrt3}(\text{unreliable})$$
all of these expressions are real, but involves complex number to express them in radicals because they are too awesome, so we left with the two expression but with the same value
$$\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i-4\sqrt3}+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{8}\sqrt[3]{4i+4\sqrt3}=-\frac{i\sqrt{-18+\frac{-3-3i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{-3+3i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}}}{6}$$
and both were equals $\cos 50°$